# SharePoint 2013 Export Report in semicolon delimited file

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013

how I can export reports from SharePoint 2013 in semicolon csv file.

I did that in SharePoint 2010 by applying some change the Reporting server, but the reporting service in SharePoint 2013 is different from SharePoint 2010.

In case you need it:
- I have 2 servers,  one for SharePoint 2013 and the second is the database server (mssql 2014).

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here [Adding a custom rendering extension to SQL Server Reporting Services 2012 for SharePoint 2010 integrated mode](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9d3bd212-3f24-4896-86ea-c3b2b964e8df/adding-a-custom-rendering-extension-to-sql-server-reporting-services-2012-for-sharepoint-2010?forum=sqlreportingservices)

```
For Pipe delimited text format

-Sharepoint managemnt shell as Admin

-Run Get-SPRSServiceApplication to get GUID ID

-Run New-SPRSExtension -identity YOUR GUID ID -ExtensionType "Render" -name "TxtPipeDelimited" -TypeName "Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering" -ServerDirectives "<OverrideNames><Name Language='en-US'>TXT Pipe Delimited</Name></OverrideNames>" -ExtensionConfiguration "<DeviceInfo><FieldDelimiter>|</FieldDelimiter><NoHeader>true</NoHeader><FileExtension>txt</FileExtension><ExcelMode>False</ExcelMode><Encoding>ASCII</Encoding></DeviceInfo>"

-Run iisreset in Cmd line as admin(development server not production)
```

This will export data without header, if you need to keep the header remove

```
<NoHeader>true</NoHeader>
```